# Python - restructure dictionary of lits in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Hi guys I have a dict id_dict where I have some keys. In this keys there are lists as values (sometimes only one item somtimes 4). (These are names of components)

my dict id_dict is created **dynamically** and the keys and values will always change.

Comment: Note that you also wound append second and third elements on lists anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S = {'G': ['crypto'], 'T': ['update', 'monitor', 'ipforum'], 'F': ['update'], 'M': ['crypto','update']}

R = {}
for key, value_list in S.items():
    for value in value_list:
        if value not in R:
            R[value] = []
        R[value].append(key)

print(R)
```

Output:

```
{'crypto': ['G', 'M'], 'update': ['T', 'F', 'M'], 'monitor': ['T'], 'ipforum': ['T']}
```

Comment: use `R = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: I excluded that on purpose because it needs an additional import

Comment: @SerialLazer Do you have any ideas for unit tests for this case? Any assertions that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

you are actually trying to assign the components list you're iterating in as a key of the dictionary, this is what will cause the error.
try by simply doing:

```
            component_dict[component] = id
```

Comment: {'update': ['T'], 'monitor': ['T'], 'ipforum': ['T']}

Comment: I only get this back @Jotes

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like:

```
new_dic = {}

for k, v in dic.items():
    for ele in v:
        if ele not in new_dic:
            new_dic[ele] = []
        new_dic[ele].append(k)
new_dic
```

Note the append

Answer (score 0):

It seems that u call `components` Instead of `component` and that cannot be a dict key, this si what causes the error,
In addition you didnt set it as a list and just assigned the value, you need to assign a list of it doesnt exist, and append to it if it does

So:

```
If dict_components.get(component):
    dict_components[component].append(id)
else: 
    dict_components[component] = [id]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'G': ['crypto'], 'T': ['update', 'monitor', 'ipforum'], 'F': ['update'], 'M': ['crypto', 'update']}
d1 = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    for x in v:
        d1[x].append(k)
print(d1)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'crypto': ['G', 'M'], 'update': ['T', 'F', 'M'], 'monitor': ['T'], 'ipforum': ['T']})
```

Comment: This one also worked but it needs an additional import which is not necessary Thank u though!!

Comment: @Newone11 while the code "needs an additional import" (which is core python) it makes the code shorter and more readable. It avoids `if value not in R:
            R[value] = []`

Comment: I understand but what about defaultdict(<class 'list'> at the beginning? Is there a way not to have this part in that object? Cause it doesn't look nice :/ I hope u understand

Comment: `defaultdict` just extends `dict`. You can use it just as any "regular" dict

Comment: Do you have any ideas for unit tests for this case? Assertions that makes sense? I only did assert d1 is not None

Comment: @Newone11 I dont think you need to add any unit tests. The code is simple enough.

Comment: I think the same way but I have to :/

Comment: loop over `d.values()` and them to s `set`. The final set should be the same as `d1.keys()`

Comment: Thanks!!! @balderman I have posted another question would you mind to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

The easies way will be to use *collections.defaultdict* - which will save you from multiple tests

```
from collections import defaultdict
source = {'G': ['crypto'], 
          'T': ['update', 'monitor', 'ipforum'], 
          'F': ['update'], 
          'M': ['crypto','update']}

components = defaultdict(list)
for key, values_list in source.items():
    for value in values_list:
        components[value].append(key)
```

And the result will be

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'crypto': ['G', 'M'],
             'update': ['T', 'F', 'M'],
             'monitor': ['T'],
             'ipforum': ['T']})
```

As an alternative, you may create regular *dict* and use *setdefault* method to create lists

```
components = {}
for key, values_list in source.items():
    for value in values_list:
        components.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```